# ubuntu/kde - defining labels for partitions

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, kde

I've got kubuntu 12.04 LTS. I use dolphin file manager a lot. On the left I've got `Places` panel, which you can see below:

[image]

The question is - how can I configure my system to display my custom labels for those partitions? For example, there is a partition called "Nowy" - this is a windows partition that has been named "Nowy" from windows level. And during installation ubuntu figured it out somehow. I get confused which partition is which and I want to name them. I checked /etc/fstab, but didn't find where to put partition label there.

---

edit:

When I open KDE partition manager, I can display the partition properties. Unfortunately, I'm unable to change/set partition label. Is it possible only at creation time (in my case - during system install)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install GParted with:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Launch it, right click the each partition and select `Label`. Type the label and then apply all changes.

It is probably doable with KDE's partition manager too.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm unable to change/set the label... don't know why. I've updated my question.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz what if you unmount first (except root partition whose label can be changed from a live DVD/USB with GParted / KDE partition manager)?